# $\varphi$-irreducibility of Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have seen the discussion here: [$\psi$-irreducibility of Markov Chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60122/psi-irreducibility-of-markov-chains).

For the example in the last paragraph where $X=\{a,b\}$ and the Markov chain can only jump from $a$ to $a$ and $b$ to $b$ with probability one, can we let $\mathcal{B}(X)=\{\varnothing, \{a,b\}\}$ with $\varphi(\varnothing)=0$ and $\varphi(\{a,b\})=1$? Does it mean the Markov chain becomes $\varphi$-irreducible?

Comment: Since we are dealing with a countable space then I believe  $\mathbb{B}(X)\neq \{\emptyset, \{a,b\}\}$. The definition of irreducibility requires this to hold for $\mathbb{B}(X)$ the power set. If we consider only a finite state space markov chain then your chain is reducible into two absorption states. Which leads me to believe it can't be $\psi$-irredubible.

Comment: If that were the case then wouldn't that imply that for all Markov processes there exists a maximal- irreducibility measure. At that point then why specify a specific type of markov chain for something that holds for all chains. If I am allowed to specify the $\sigma$ algebra as oppose to the Borel  $\mathbb{B}(X)$ then  I can probably find an irreducibility measure but you run into the situation I just alluded: a reducible chain in finite transition and a $\varphi$-irreducible in a general context. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I am not sure whether $\mathcal{X}$ should be a power set, but I think it only need to be $sigma$-algebra. I have found a note indicating there exists a $\varphi$-irreducible Markov chain but not irreducible; see Example 3.5 in https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/sf3953/Material/L3.pdf

Comment: I see. In that example they are using the kernel as a transition which gives me $\varphi$ irreducibilty but my original chain does not communicate. I still believe you need the Borel field, but this might be above my pay rate.

Comment: Yes, I think the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (field) is needed. But why is $\mathcal{B}(X)=\{\varnothing, \{a, b\}\}$ not Borel field if we define the topology $\tau=\{\varnothing, \{a, b\}\}$?

Comment: Because you have defined the trivial sigma field and then many measure become an irreducibility measure since $P(x,X)=1$ from any $x$ and we just need the measure to satisfy $\mu(X)>0$ and then I am only considering transitioning into X since this is the only set I have deemed measurable. Not a very interesting markov chain